# SQL Domain Group with one member Read Only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a group in AD called 'Domain\SQL Admins', containing 3 high level employees and 2 generic usernames (with very strong passwords).  This group has been added to the various SQL servers and given god rights.

My question - Is there a way to downgrade one of the generic usernames to read only on one particular server?

Example:
Desired results - within in this 'Domain\SQL Admins' group:

- Domain\JDoe (sysadmin)
- Domain\JSmith (sysadmin)
- Domain\DJones (sysadmin)
- Domain\ServerUser (sysadmin)
- Domain\JobRunner (read only)

*I am thinking i may need to remove the read only user and create a new group / add this user specifically to each server in question.*

Thanks.

SQL 2008 R2

Comment: Take JobRunner out of the group and assign it's permissions server by server.

Comment: Bummer.  I was hoping for some overlooked fix.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have used AD Groups to create logins and give permission/ assigned roles. If a user is a member of a group and he/she will have all permissions/Roles assigned to that group. Even if you create a separate login for that user and take away permissions on that individual login level, that user will still have permissions since he/she is member of a group who has all the permission.

You will need to remove that user from the AD group. Create another group for read-only permission or use that user's account to create a login an give read-only permission to that user.